# Where does the execution control gets transfered to after the OnClickListener's OnClick returns ? Code attached

Tags: android, actionlistener

Relevant Code Snippet:

```
public class MyPreference extends Preference {

    public MyPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.ctx = context;

        this.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Preference has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to do some processing(basically call finish()) once the onPreferenceClick handler returns me true.

Pointers?

**EDIT**
Added finish() inside the onClick but its not working. No error. Just a Toast and nothing else. My intention is to close the app once MyPreferenceis clicked

```
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Preference has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                MainPreferenceActivity mainPref = new MainPreferenceActivity();
                mainPref.finish();

                return true;
            }
```

Probably I am doing it incorrectly. Creating a newInstance of MainActivity will not kill the parent MainActivity I guess, right? I am new to Java n android. Sorry :( !

Comment: No where.. its usually an anonymous class.. It gets finished... Thats it.. For finishing Why do you wait that method to return.. After all you are the one coding it.. So finish it inside **Onclick** method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Debugging the Code with Eclipse where you can set the Debugging Points and can check the flow and also different values in every variable. Even you can check step by step debugging.

Moving to next Debug point with f8 and Debugging with step by step is with f6.

This can be helpful top check every where in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trace your code's excution flow ,I suggest you to use  Log.e(TAG,""), and obeserve it in your Logcat window(Eclipse compostion).
For your question, i have two ideas:

1)if you want to finish,then finish it in the OnClick method.

2)You can also set a flag inside your onClick method,like:

```
if(flag) {
    doSomething();
}
```

while the doSomething routine is right what you want to do if the flag has been set.